# SQL Select with conditional data for next row

Tags: c++, sql, database, data-manipulation

I want to retrieve some close stock data and compare it with the two dates I choose. For example, If I want to see the change in a stock price from `1/1/20` and `1/1/21`, I would like it to go through all the stocks listed and return to me a comparison of the prices on those two days. The comparison is the change in close, percentage change, close on previous day, close on last day, last day time (or at least that is the data I want to retrieve from the database).

Currently, what I have to make it work is the query
`"SELECT Code, Close, Date FROM StockData WHERE DateInSeconds = " + from + " OR DateInSeconds = " + to + " ORDER BY Code ASC, DateInSeconds";`

```
Code is the code name for a company
Close is the close price
Date is the formatted date (in a string) 'dd-mm-yyyy'
DateInSeconds is the timestamp for that date so that I can sort by it
from is the timestamp for the first date
to is the timestamp for the second date
```

that loads in the closes for day1 and day2, and then my C++ program iterates through the array of closes and check if the next element is the same code (because it may miss dates, or not be up to date), and if it is, do the comparison. This is quite inefficient because I copy the data into an array, and then manipulate it and copy it into another array, whereas I would just prefer it if the query would send the correct data over to avoid this.

An example of the table would be

```
Code       Date         Close      DateInSeconds

ASX     01-01-2000      1.00       946645200
ASX     02-01-2000      1.10       946731600
.
.
ASX     02-07-2021      50.00      1625148000
.
.
ANZ     01-01-2000      1.00       946645200
.
.
```

with some dummy close values.

And an example of an output with dates `(Date, Close: { 01-01-2021, 100 }, { 02-01-2021, 150 })` (stored in an array in the program)

```
Code   CloseChange   CloseChangePercent   Previous       Last         Date
ASX    +50.00        +50.00%              100.00         150.00      02-01-2021
.
Company 2...
Company 3...
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to combine 2 rows of input into 1 row of output, you can do this with a join:

```
SELECT
    sdfrom.Code,
    sdfrom.DateInSeconds as FromDate,
    sdfrom.Close as FromClose,
    sdto.DateInSeconds as ToDate,
    sdto.Close as ToClose
FROM StockData sdfrom
    INNER JOIN StockData sdto ON (sdfrom.Code = sdto.Code AND sdto.DateInSeconds = @toDate)
WHERE sdfrom.DateInSeconds = @fromDate
```

This is an inner join, so both the from and to records have to exist.

Comment: Im a bit confused with the statement, `sdfrom` is the date? In my example, `StockData` is the table. And what is that going to output once joining?

Comment: sdfrom is a table alias. The query is joining StockData to itself, so I have created 2 table aliases, sdfrom (StockData from) and sdto (StockData to). It will output 5 columns: 'Code', 'FromDate' - this an alias for sdfrom.DateInSeconds, and so on

Comment: Why is that so smart, it even works for missing values :DDDD awesome!!!

Comment: I wish I could take credit for inventing SQL. :)